# Parallelism with a shared interlocked variable

Tags: c#

Is there a way to share a variable amongst a parallel method? I have this current.
I know there is a way to do this but I can't seem to find the code amongst the microsoft documents on how to do it. I think its some type of lock or interlock, but can't seem to find it.

```
List<string> bob = new List<string>();

bob.Add("hey");
bob.Add("asdasf");
bob.Add("dfghfghd");
bob.Add("rtertdf");
bob.Add("2535dfgd");
bob.Add("sdfsdfzcxv");
bob.Add("sfgsdgsdfh");
bob.Add("23454567");
bob.Add("fgjuoiyhji");
bob.Add("ghjnbvdfg");
bob.Add("fghdtu5645");
bob.Add("565yhfhgh");
bob.Add("ewqrwy77684");
bob.Add("nbndrthw2");
Parallel.ForEach(bob, peer =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(peer + " : " + currentCount); // how can I make currentCount shared?
    
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do this. You were almost there. Just need to use an Interlocked.Increment on counter.

```
int count = 0;
List<string> bob = new List<string>();

bob.Add("hey");
bob.Add("asdasf");
bob.Add("dfghfghd");
bob.Add("rtertdf");
bob.Add("2535dfgd");
bob.Add("sdfsdfzcxv");
bob.Add("sfgsdgsdfh");
bob.Add("23454567");
bob.Add("fgjuoiyhji");
bob.Add("ghjnbvdfg");
bob.Add("fghdtu5645");
bob.Add("565yhfhgh");
bob.Add("ewqrwy77684");
bob.Add("nbndrthw2");
Parallel.ForEach(bob, peer =>
{
    var currentCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
    Console.WriteLine(peer + " : " + currentCount);
    
});
```

this produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I meant.